# Game Center Turnbased Matchmaking Issues

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

So I'm working on a turn based game, utilizing game center.  I have most of the ins and outs figured out. However, when a player resigns from the match GameCenter automatically tries to fill that players slot with a player searching for a match.  I do not want this behavior to occur and can't for the life of me find a way to disable it.

Note: I realize that I may not be clear on how I want the app to preform so here is the flow that I would like gameplay to follow in the event that someone resigns.

Match is filled to capacity > Player resigns and their game pieces are removed from the game > People already in the match continue to play and no new participants are allowed to join mid match.

If anyone has any insight into this issue I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the behavior you want?  Should you just end the game if someone resigns?

Comment: This is the flow I would like.  Match is filled to capacity > Player resigns and their game pieces are removed from the game > People already in the match continue to play and no new participants are allowed to join mid match.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, but you might want to manage the list of matches on your own.  After you retrieve the list of current matches, you can check the status of a match and decide if you want to list it for players to join or not, based on the custom match data that you store.